# $D^2$ not topological manifold without boundary

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I want to prove that the two dimensional disk $D^2$ is not a topological manifold without boundary, i.e. there is a point $x\in D^2$ such that $x$ has no neighbourhood $U$ with $U$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I choose $x=1\in\partial D^2$. Without loss of generality, let $U$ be a contractible open neighbourhood and suppose $U$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $f:U\to\mathbb{R}^2$ a homeomorphism. Is it true that $U\setminus\{1\}$ is contractible? And what is the reason it is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not pick $U$ to be a small open disk intersected with $D^2$? E.g., $U = B_\epsilon(x) \cap D^2$. Then $U\setminus \{x\}$ is contractible because it is star-shaped.

Comment: But I have to show that there does not exist an open neighbourhood of 1 homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, so I can not pick it.

Comment: Yes, but any open neighborhood of $1$ contains one of this form. And no open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (the image under the proposed homeomorphism of this small open disk) has the property that removing a point gives you a contractible set.

Comment: So, if I read correctly, this is what you are saying: Let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of 1 homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, with $f$ the homeomorphism. Then, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $X:=B_\epsilon(1)\cap D^2\subset U$. By restricting $f$, we get a homeomorphism between $X$ and some open $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then, $X\setminus\{1\}$ is homeomorphic to $V\setminus\{f(1)\}$, but $X\setminus\{1\}$ is contractible since it is star shaped and $V\setminus\{f(1)\}$ is not contractible

Comment: @James That's right.

Comment: How can I easily show that $X\setminus\{1\}$ is star shaped?

Comment: Thinking of $D^2\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and $1=(1,0)$: the line between $y=(1-\epsilon/2,0) \in X$ and any point in $X\setminus\{1\}$ lies completely in $X\setminus\{1\}$.

Comment: Can we also say that $X\setminus\{1\}$ is convex?

Comment: @James yes, definitely.